# Including partial scripts as part of a POSIX shell

Tags: bash, posix

I can't get a straight answer ANYWHERE about this question.

In BASH, you can include a 'partial' script and execute it inline in the rest of your bash script with the following syntax:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

. ~/my-partial-include-preamble-script.in.sh
# do stuff here 
# .
# . 
# .
```

The question is this: is this syntax in the POSIX standard, and if not, is there some syntax in the standard which accomplishes the same thing? Is there a link anyone can post showing where in the POSIX standard this syntax is defined (if applicable)?

Comment: Here is the standard, look yourself: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just searched myself: The answer is [yes, it's part of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot).

Comment: thank you. I'm all for reading the manual. I just didn't know the directive was named 'dot' and therefore couldn't find the man page. I appreciate your pointing it out!